# How to create self-signed SAN certificate in IIS?

Tags: ssl, iis, ssl-certificate

Is it possible to create a self-signed SAN ssl certificate in IIS?
If so, how do I go about creating it? In IIS, I only see the option of creating a normal ssl certificate:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately, IIS manager cannot create certificates or requests with SAN extension. You have to use something else. For example, PowerShell or certreq.exe tool (both are included in the box).

## PowerShell

### Minimum required parameters

```
New-SelfsignedCertificate `
    -DnsName "mysite.com","www.mysite.com" `
    -CertStoreLocation cert:\localmachine\my
```

### More detailed parameters

```
New-SelfsignedCertificate -Subject "CN=www.mysite.com" `
    -DnsName "mysite.com","www.mysite.com" `
    -EKU "Server Authentication" `
    -KeySpec "KeyExchange" ` 
    -KeyUsage "DigitalSignature", "KeyEncipherment" `
    -FriendlyName "My web site"
    -NotAfter $([datetime]::now.AddYears(1)) `
    -CertStoreLocation cert:\localmachine\my
```

## CertReq.exe

Prepare INF template file (with .inf file extension) with the following contents:

```
[NewRequest]
Subject = "CN=www.mysite.com"
KeyLength = 2048
KeyAlgorithm = RSA
ProviderName = "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider"
MachineKeySet = true
KeySpec = 1
KeyUsage = 0xa0
RequestType = Cert
[EnhancedKeyUsageExtension]
OID=1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 ; server authentication
[Extensions] 
2.5.29.17 = "{text}" 
_continue_ = "dns=mysite.com&" 
_continue_ = "dns=www.mysite.com"
```

And then execute the following command against this INF file:

```
certreq -new path\myinftemplate.inf
```

Comment: Hi, what's the difference between common name and DnsName? @Crypt32

Comment: After using the powershell script, what command do I use to allow this script to run? Because it seems stuck after that.

Comment: My powershell says `the term new self-signed certifcate is not recognised as a cmdlet`

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo in command name. Now the name is correct.

Answer (score 2):

What version of Windows?  If it is a newer version of Windows, it would probably be easier to just open up powershell and use the [New-SelfSignedCertificate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/new-selfsignedcertificate) commandlet.  You can use the `-DnsName` to provide a list of all the names you want in your SAN.

Comment: It's windows server 2012. I tried, but my powershell says `the term new self-signed certifcate is not recognised as a cmdlet`

Comment: Because the command is “New-SelfSignedCertificate” not “new self-signed certificate”.